# Couldn't display list of items in Django template + Angularjs variable

Tags: angularjs, django

I have below code in my template which displays the tags that were entered via input text using Angularjs in Django template.

```
<div id="tags" style="border:none;width:370px;">
  {% for cat in categories %}            
  <span class="tag" ng-repeat="data in dataset" id="4" 
                    ng-click="removeData_sk($index)">
    {%verbatim%} {{data.name}} {%endverbatim%} {{ cat.sname }}
  </span>
  {% endfor %}
  <div>    
    <input type="text" style="margin-left:-5px;" id="inptags" value="" 
           placeholder="Add ur 5 main categories (Enter)" 
           ng-model="inputVal" ng-keypress="skEnter($event)"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above span tag, `{{data.name}}` is angularjs variable -> that is set via the input text.
And `{{ cat.sname }}` is my Django template variable -> which basically has list of values from categories (from the server).

This doesn't show me the list of categories that were returned from server as spans.. What am I missing?

How can I display the list of spans that were returned from server.. and at the same time, how can I use angularjs variable as and when required.. Basically, I need to have these two kinds of variables synced.

I used Angularjs in Django powered site first time.

Earlier without angularjs, code looks to be like this -

```
        <div id="tags" style="border:none;margin-left:25px;width:70%;">
                {% for cat in categories %}            
              <span class="tag" id="4">{{ cat.sname }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
              <div>    
                <input type="text" style="margin-left:-5px;overflow:hidden" id="inptags" value="" placeholder="Add ur 5 main categories (enter ,)" />            
              </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I already used verbatim.. How is it duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this just in case if it helps someone in need.

I solved it by assigning the array to my dataset variable in my Angularjs.
It got the list of categories as spans.

```
$scope.dataset=d1_init;
```

d1_init is my javascript variable, which contains the list of categories that were assigned from django tags.

So my code in the Django template is -

```
<span class="tag" ng-repeat="data in dataset" id="4" ng-click="removeData_sk($index)"> {%verbatim%} {{data.name}} {%endverbatim%} </span>
```